# Split a string and find the occurrence percentage

Tags: r, string, split, tidyr, data-manipulation

I have a vector value where the separator is `'` and I would like to find the occurrence of each text. How to get around with this? many thanks in advance.

```
val1 <- c("ab, cd, ef", "", "gh", "ab")
```

Expected Answer

```
 ab   cd   ef  gh
 40%  20% 20%  20%
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In base R:

```r
tab <- table(trimws(unlist(strsplit(val1, ","))))
100 * tab / sum(tab)
#> 
#> ab cd ef gh 
#> 40 20 20 20
```

<sup>Created on 2022-05-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: You could use `proportions` `proportions(table(unlist(strsplit(val1, ",\\s*")))) * 100`

Answer (score 2):

```
library(tidyverse)
val1 %>%
  str_split(pattern = ", ") %>% 
  unlist %>% 
  tibble(strings = . ) %>% 
  filter(strings != "") %>% 
  count(strings) %>% 
  mutate(perc = n / sum(n))

# A tibble: 4 x 3
  strings     n  perc
  <chr>   <int> <dbl>
1 ab          2   0.4
2 cd          1   0.2
3 ef          1   0.2
4 gh          1   0.2
```